Deserialized JSON showing NULL elements
We're calling an API that returns JSON data structured as follows:
[
  {
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Gates",
    "email": "bill.gates@microsoft.com"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Steve",
    "lastName": "Balmer",
    "email": "steve.balmer@microsoft.com"
  }
]

After copying this data, and using the "Paste JSON as Classes" option in Visual Studio 2022, we have the following class:
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

If we run the following test, our employees object contains 2 elements, but the value for each element is NULL.
 string sJSON = @"[{""firstName"":""Bill"",""lastName"":""Gates"",""email"":""bill.gates@microsoft.com""},{""firstName"":""Steve"",""lastName"":""Balmer"",""email"":""steve.balmer@microsoft.com""}]";

 Rootobject[] employees = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject[]>(sJSON);

Any idea what is wrong here?

The root JSON container is an array of objects containing "firstName", "lastName" and "email", so you need to do JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1 []>(sJSON).  There is nothing in the JSON corresponding to Rootobject, is is not needed.

Incidentally, this sort of problem is easy to diagnose by serializing an instance of your model, them comparing the serialized JSON with the JSON you need to deserialize.  If you were to serialize a Rootobject [] array you would see an extra level of nesting not present in the JSON you need to deserialize.

First of all, your class should have different structure:
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

Then to deserialize use:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

var employees = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Employee[]>(json, options);

Also you can take a look here JsonPropertyAttribute

Based on your Json Rootobject should be an array.
You can use Convert Json to C# Classes Online to generate models for your Json.
